# How do I proxy all my docker container network traffic through tor?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, networking, ip, tor

Let's say I have a tor daemon running on port `6969`, how would I create a ubuntu docker container that makes ALL the traffic go through the daemon/proxy. And I mean ALL the traffic including `TCP`, `UDP` and all the traffic that the docker container makes. Is this even possible with docker?

Basically i want to create a container that proxies ALL traffic through the daemon so if I run for example this command:

```sh
curl https://api.ipify.org
```

it should return the IP address that the tor daemon is using and not the IP address of my machine.